# How do I cheaply split emails between different servers dependent on the user its sent to?

Tags: domain-name-system, email, mx-record

I'm helping a friend start a small business, he wants an email on his domain (contact@domain.com) to have access to Google Drive storage to be able to upload files and share them with clients.

He also wants a series of inboxes for him and his coworkers (*user*@domain.com)

My current setup (that he's not satisfied by) is: all email to his domain goes to smtp.google.com. If the address matches contact@domain.com, it is stored in the Google inbox. If it matches *user*@domain.com, it is forwarded to *user*@mail.domain.com, where it is sent to an IMAP server hosted by MXroute.

This works fine, until *user*@domain.com replies to an email, and exposes that they've actually recieved the email at *user*@mail.domain.com! I'm aware of customizing identities, but my friend and his coworkers are not tech savvy enough to set them up on their own, on all of their devices. It also requires that *user*@domain log into their email with *user*@mail.domain.com, which also might create further confusion.

Is there a way to avoid this? Thanks in advance

Comment: Why splitting it between different servers? Your making it yourself unnecessary difficult. How many users are there involved with this SMB? With some proper sizing one server is usually sufficient for a SMB.

Comment: Is about cost in regards to Google Workspace user licenses? This sounds like a lot of nonsense to save a few dollars a month.

Answer (score 0):

The way to prevent this is create accounts and mailboxes at one provider and don't split it like it was.

I have seen a lot people here you use if you spin it that up on a VM, you can't have outgoing smtp, mailbox access using pop3 or imaps and spam filtering in one solution.

https://www.iredmail.org/

---

Usually a mail server has a mailbox database or more than one mailbox database, and you don't spread them over servers, but you there are spread over storage volumes, the mailserver itself decides on which mailbox database a mailbox is going to be placed. But multiple mailbox databases not what you see at an SMB, but at larger organizations.
So especially at a SMB I think there is no need to spread users.

Keep in mind that with a self hosted mail server not only the costs for the server come, but also storage, and maintenance come

---

A much simpler solution would be to create Microsoft 365 accounts and acquire licenses or create Google Workspaces accounts.

Answer (score 0):

Don’t have any email route to google. Put all mailboxes on the alternate mail hosting provider and route email directly to them.

You don’t need to have mail flow to Google, to use Google Drive and/or Google workspace. You can have domain.com validated at both providers and have login names for contact@domain.com (or others) at Google without actually sending/receiving mail there. After all, all you are doing is logging in to Google drive. You just need a username, not an active mailbox.

To make sure there are no problems with your emails going to junk mail on the receiving side, make sure your SPF / DKIM records for the domain are setup to allow Google and the alternate mail provider to send mail for your domain. This way, any outbound email from contact@domain.com sent by Google will still flow properly in to the recipients’ inbox, such as when a new sharing link is sent. Although I’m not sure this last part is necessary, because I’m not sure that Google drive sharing emails actually come from contact@domain.com and not some other Google email address.